# Changing PrimaryGroupID for admin? Mac OSX 10.9

Tags: macos, mac

Im wondering if changing the PrimaryGroupID of a user to 20 (which is the administrator group) will grant the user admin. Is there a possibility of corruption problems ect doing it this way?

By the way, I'm using Directory Utility to change this (under the directory editor tab). I'm not sure if this will mess something up, or grant the user administrative rights.

Answer (score 2):

First, on OS X the group 20 is the "staff" group, and is the normal primary group for user accounts. The admin group is 80.

Setting a user's primary group ID to 80 will add them to the admin group, and hence give them admin rights on the computer. I don't know of any specific problems this would cause, but it's not the normal way to make a user an admin, and hence I wouldn't consider it optimal. I'd rather make someone an admin by adding a secondary membership in the admin group with the command `sudo dseditgroup -o edit -a usernametomakeadmin -t user admin`, or just by checking the "Allow user to administer this computer" box in the Users & Groups preferences.